# Shell script within .app bundle errors out

Tags: bash, macos, shell, applescript, sh

I use a shell script named ***myapp.command*** to open an app such as the Microsoft PowerShell app:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh
```

The script works fine. However, when I put the same script inside a macOS bundle (called myapp.app), it does not work. The error message I get is, *myapp.app quit unexpectedly*.

Error report reveals that the error occurs in /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp.command.

Exception type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information: abort() called

The contents of Info.plist are as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>1.0, Copyright © 2019 MyCompany, All Rights Reserved</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>mycompany.myapp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2019 MyCompany, All Rights Reserved.</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>ShellScript</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>myapp.command</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>MyCompany</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>main.nib</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How can I fix/troubleshoot this?

Comment: "It's criminal. There ought to be a law. Criminal."

Comment: Odds are it's a gatekeeper issue; I don't see any appropriate permissions in the info.plist. I assume this is an AppleScript app, so can you show the relevant code (the line(s) where you call the shell script)? You may have to give it permission to control other apps in System Preferences☞Security & Privacy☞Privacy☞Automation

Comment: It is a command line app made with .net core. **myapp.command** works when I double-click on it. I can also open the app by entering `./path/to/file` in Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwsh` crashes because it is not connected to any tty

A work-around is to tell the Terminal App to launch it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e '
    tell app "Terminal"
        do script "/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/7/pwsh; exit $?"
        activate
    end tell
'
```